Chords and Tangents on Elliptic Curves Over Arbitrary Fields
I've been reading some books (e.g. Definition 3 in this chapter on elliptic curve cryptography or Group Law Algorithm 2.3 from The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves) which define the group operation on two points on an elliptic curve over a field using the chord or tangent line through these two points.
What I'm wondering about is (if a reason/intuition exists) why or how these algebraic definitions that, at least to me, seem to be derived from the geometric interpretations (secant and tangent lines on elliptic curves in nice and intuitive topologies like real numbers) generalize to arbitrary fields like finite fields.

The short answer is that everything in sight is algebraic in the sense that it's defined by polynomials. Polynomial identities true over $\mathbb{Z}$ are true over every field simultaneously. And e.g. the associativity of the addition law is such an identity.
